# Modular inverse question

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem, euclidean-algorithm

I am trying to find the x  $$113x\equiv 311 \mod 653$$ but using Euclidean algorithm I calculate until here $$(-152)(113)\equiv 1  \mod 653$$ 
This negative number is confusing me. How can I go further to find the inverse?
Or how can I change $$x\equiv -152 \mod 653$$  so that there wouldn't be any negative number? 
Can I simplify the question using Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: $x \equiv -b \mod{a} \implies x \equiv a-b \mod{a}$.

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse and we get $x=153$

Answer (score 0):

If x must not necessarily be an integer, we may write:

$654 ≡  1 mod 653$

$311ˣ 654 ≡ 311 mod 653$

comparing this with congruence $113 x ≡ 311 mod 653$ we get

$ x =\frac{ 311ˣ654}{ 113}$